# Find the total number of roots of a certain polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Find the total number of roots of a certain polynomial.

I would be interested to find the exact number of roots of a certain polynomial that depends on avariable $m \in \mathbb R$. I would like to know if there is a specific method that can help me with different given polynomials.

I made a research and I found a theorem called Rouche’sTheorem:

> Rouche’sTheorem: Let two functions  $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be analytic inside
> and on a  simple closed curve C, and suppose that  $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ at
> each point on $C$. Then  $f(z)$ and $f(z) + g(z)$ have the same  number of
> zeros, inside $C$

I thought that this might be usefeul.

For a particular case let's analyse:

the function:
$$ f(x)=x^4-mx^3+6x^2-4x+1$$
it seems like $$f(x)=(x-1)^4+4x^3-mx^3$$

Might this help me?
I would enjoy any help in this regard.

Comment: The total number of zeros of a polynomial with degree $n$ is... $n$. You must mean "zeros inside a certain region".

Comment: @JeanMarie They could also mean total number of roots without counting multiplicity. Which is more elementary and probably doesn't need anything as complicated as Rouche.

Comment: There's also the distinction between real and complex roots to consider.

Comment: Maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4

Comment: This might be helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem